# Inner width of span content iPhone

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone, webkit

I've got a problem with text size in my iPhone.

The problem is it's makes me different width of text having the same font-size: 15px.

Here is the screen-shot from my computer:
[image]

Inner width of span is 40px;
But in my iPhone inner width is 45px. I found out about it putting a javascript code to get inner width in my phone.
It happens with all button on the right.
The screen-shot from my iPhone:
[image]

I tried adding "-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;" but it doesn't work.
I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

yeah, I think size of pixel on desktop and mobile is different..
you can try `font-size:1em` size using `em` will follow the width of the screen.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work. Having the same problem. I suggesting that it's a problem with width of spaces between letters, however letter-spacing not working for iPhone.